# ggplot2: italicising only certain x axis columns

Tags: r, ggplot2

In my box plot, I'm trying to keep the x axis column label "WT" plain, whilst converting the other 7 column labels into italic text. I used `element_text`, but this caused all of the labels to turn italic. Is there some way to isolate the "WT" column label to be able to change it to plain text?

```
ggplot(edtct2)+
  geom_boxplot(aes(x=Mutant, y=Chlorophyll))+
  labs(title = "Total Chlorophyll levels across SP2 Mutants", 
       y = "Chlorophyll (nmol/mg tissue)")+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1, face = "italic"))+
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))
```

The data that I used is from a cvs file that I inputted and modified, and so is in the following format.

```
       Mutant Chlorophyll
1          WT        1.14
2          WT        1.33
3          WT        1.29
4          WT        1.65
5        ppi1        0.59
6        ppi1        0.80
7        ppi1        0.61
8        ppi1        0.67
9       sp2-4        1.15
10      sp2-4        1.08
11      sp2-4        1.00
12      sp2-4        1.01
13   sp2 ppi1        1.02
14   sp2 ppi1        0.82
15   sp2 ppi1        0.65
16   sp2 ppi1        0.84
17 sp2-3 ppi1        0.91
18 sp2-3 ppi1        0.77
19 sp2-3 ppi1        0.78
20 sp2-3 ppi1        0.85
21 sp2-5 ppi1        0.78
22 sp2-5 ppi1        1.04
23 sp2-5 ppi1        0.90
24 sp2-5 ppi1        0.97
25 sp2-6 ppi1        0.74
26 sp2-6 ppi1        0.84
27 sp2-6 ppi1        0.86
28 sp2-6 ppi1        0.88
29 sp2-8 ppi1        1.25
30 sp2-8 ppi1        1.25
31 sp2-8 ppi1        1.30
32 sp2-8 ppi1        1.34
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. When you ask a question, please provide a minimal reproducible data. Here you have `dtct2` in your code. But nobody has access to the data except you. This gives difficult time for SO users to help you out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define the `face` with a vector.

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(edtct2)+
  geom_boxplot(aes(x=Mutant, y=Chlorophyll))+
  labs(title="Total Chlorophyll levels across SP2 Mutants", 
       y="Chlorophyll (nmol/mg tissue)")+
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=45, hjust=1, face=c(rep("italic", 7), "plain")),
        plot.title=element_text(hjust=0.5))
```

## Result

[image]

---

*Data:*

```
edtct2 <- structure(list(Mutant = c("WT", "WT", "WT", "WT", "ppi1", "ppi1", 
"ppi1", "ppi1", "sp2-4", "sp2-4", "sp2-4", "sp2-4", "sp2 ppi1", 
"sp2 ppi1", "sp2 ppi1", "sp2 ppi1", "sp2-3 ppi1", "sp2-3 ppi1", 
"sp2-3 ppi1", "sp2-3 ppi1", "sp2-5 ppi1", "sp2-5 ppi1", "sp2-5 ppi1", 
"sp2-5 ppi1", "sp2-6 ppi1", "sp2-6 ppi1", "sp2-6 ppi1", "sp2-6 ppi1", 
"sp2-8 ppi1", "sp2-8 ppi1", "sp2-8 ppi1", "sp2-8 ppi1"), Chlorophyll = c(1.14, 
1.33, 1.29, 1.65, 0.59, 0.8, 0.61, 0.67, 1.15, 1.08, 1, 1.01, 
1.02, 0.82, 0.65, 0.84, 0.91, 0.77, 0.78, 0.85, 0.78, 1.04, 0.9, 
0.97, 0.74, 0.84, 0.86, 0.88, 1.25, 1.25, 1.3, 1.34)), row.names = c(NA, 
-32L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: I have set the order to the columns using the following code
```
levcl <- levels(edtct2$Mutant)
levcl <- levcl[c(1,2, 5, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8)]

edtct2 %>%
  mutate(Mutant = factor(Mutant, levels = levcl)) ->edtct2
```
so when I enter your vector, the last column gets italicised instead of the first. Would you be able to help me change the order?

Comment: Sure, the vector just represents the position of your x-axis labels from 1 to 8. Thus, to individually set face values, just give each position its individual value. `c(rep("italic", 7), "plain")` is actually the same as `c("italic", "italic", "italic", "italic", "italic", "italic", "italic", "plain")`, so to make the first plain, do `face=c("plain", rep("italic", 7))`.